# Наполнение NavigationDrawer

Tags: android

Стоит задача, чтобы в NavigationDrawer разместились 20 пунктов, но при скроллинге всегда было видно только 3. Подскажите пожалуйста как разместить только 3 пункта, заранее спасибо)

Comment: Алгоритм такой: получить высоту экрана устройства, вычесть всё лишнее (статус бар, хедер и т. д.) и разделить на 3. Установить полученную величину в качестве высоты у итема программно.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!!!